# Using sed/bash to replace items in YAML file

Tags: bash

I want to use bash script to replace the Addresses field in YAML file with the items in the variable ORDERER_LIST dynamically i.e. if there are 3 items in the ORDERER_LIST, the items in the Addresses field will also be 3. The order does not matter.

```
ORDERER_LIST="orderer0-orderer-org:7050 orderer1-orderer-org:7050"
```

Here is the sample yaml file:

```
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: kafka
  Addresses:
    - 1 (to be replaced with item in ORDERER_LIST)
    - 2 (to be replaced with item in ORDERER_LIST)
    - etc
```

Comment: Why not use a proper syntax aware YAML parser?

Comment: You can generate or update your sample YAML (including non-referenced anchor) using `ruamel.yaml` no need to make a fragile "solution" using bash that breaks as soon as the YAML semantics stay the same, but the format is changed (from block to flow style, from plain scalars to quoted or literal style scalars)

Comment: I'm trying to minimize dependencies because i would be running on container images that do not have parsers etc. That's why I wanted to use bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than finding and replacing the elements. I think you should generate your YAML file with your bash script. You can do this in the below way.

```
#!/bin/bash
ORDERER_LIST="orderer0-orderer-org:7050 orderer1-orderer-org:7050"
IFS=' ' read -ra arr <<< "$ORDERER_LIST"
echo "Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: kafka
  Addresses:"
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "    - $i"
done
```

Output:

```
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: kafka
  Addresses:
    - orderer0-orderer-org:7050
    - orderer1-orderer-org:7050
```

Let me know if it helps.